# configuring keycloak with external postgres database

Tags: keycloak

How do we configure keycloak to use the external postgres (AWS RDS)?
We deployed it in kubernetes using quarkus distro and update dthe DB env variables in our deployment.yaml , however it is still taking the local h2 data base and not the postgres.

For better understanding providing the deployment.yaml file we are using:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "5"
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-21T16:47:29Z"
  generation: 5
  labels:
    app: keycloak
  name: keycloak
  namespace: kc***
  resourceVersion: "29233550"
  uid: 3634683e-657c-4278-9002-82a3ce64b968
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 3
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 25%
      maxUnavailable: 25%
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - start
        - --hostname=kc-test.k8.com
        - --https-certificate-file=/opt/pem/cert-pem/cert.pem
        - --https-certificate-key-file=/opt/pem/key-pem/key.pem
        - --log-level=DEBUG
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN
          value: ****
        - name: KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD
          value: *****
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: jdbc:postgresql://database.c**7irl*****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/database
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: ****
        - name: DB_USER
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_SCHEMA
          value: public
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROTOCOL
          value: dns.DNS_PING
        - name: JGROUPS_DISCOVERY_PROPERTIES
          value: dns_query=keycloak
        - name: CACHE_OWNERS_COUNT
          value: "2"
        - name: CACHE_OWNERS_AUTH_SESSIONS_COUNT
          value: "2"
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:17.0.0
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: keycloak
        ports:
        - containerPort: 7600
          name: jgroups
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /realms/master
            port: 8443
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 30
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 30
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          runAsUser: 0
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/pem/key-pem
          name: key-pem
        - mountPath: /opt/pem/cert-pem
          name: cert-pem
        - mountPath: /opt/keycloak/data
          name: keydata
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: key-pem
        name: key-pem
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: cert-pem
        name: cert-pem
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: keydata
status:
  availableReplicas: 3
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-06-21T18:02:32Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-06-21T18:02:32Z"
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-06-21T18:01:53Z"
    lastUpdateTime: "2022-06-21T18:16:41Z"
    message: ReplicaSet "keycloak-5c84476694" has successfully progressed.
    reason: NewReplicaSetAvailable
    status: "True"
    type: Progressing
  observedGeneration: 5
  readyReplicas: 3
  replicas: 3
  updatedReplicas: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your external DB also in same namespace?
if yes you can use below way.

<external postgres (AWS RDS)>secret-name in k8s secret contains all the below details.
Using this method it will dynamically fetch details from secret.

```
env:
    - name: DB_DATABASE
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: database-secret-name
          key: dbname
    - name: DB_ADDR
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: database-secret-name
          key: host
    - name: DB_PORT
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: database-secret-name
          key: port
    - name: DB_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: database-secret-name
          key: password
    - name: DB_USER
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          name: database-secret-name
          key: user
```

if your external postgres in different namespace, copy you database secret to keycloak namespace and give it a try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`DB_ADDR` is env variable for Keycloak versions 16-. Use doc for you Keycloak version https://www.keycloak.org/server/all-config

Keycloak 17+ has `KC_DB_URL`:

```
db-url

The full database JDBC URL.

If not provided, a default URL is set based on the selected database vendor. For instance, if using 'postgres', the default JDBC URL would be 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost/keycloak'.

CLI: --db-url

Env: KC_DB_URL
```

Of course configure also other env variables for your Keycloak version properly.

Comment: if i use the KC_DB_URL my pods doesn't come up healthy, and when I edit my deployment.yaml to use the DB_ADDR env variables it is coming up healthy and running fine. Does that mean I am version 16 or below? I remember updating to version 17 though.